# Can't create keyboard shortcut for sketch's mask

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut for the "Mask" action in "Sketch" app:

[image]

Using the keyboard shortcuts system preferences:

[image]

Is it possible that it doesn't work because it's not sketches top bar menu, but in it's right click menu? is there another way to add this keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yeah, it's because it's in the right-click menu. idk how to get round that, wish you luck.